# Validate date column while insert in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to validate date column while inserting in pl/sql over a whole column.
if there  is an error, I want to return a message to user to inform him about the error.
any help

I have the following function but it does not work

```
select count(TO_DATE(BIRTH_DATE,'DD/MM/YYYY')) into dt
from   TAB;

exception-    when others then 

RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20040, 'Please Enter Valid Dates For Date column in 
your data ');
```

Comment: You can't put an "invalid" date into an Oracle `DATE` column, what exactly are you trying to validate?

Comment: Also, PL/SQL is not an interactive language and it isn't really designed to inform the user.

Answer (score 0):

As APC says. 
PLSQL is not a interactive language with user.
To display error message to the user depending where use your function. 
Since Oracle Forms from java, etc ... 
Also if you run it from a command window on tools like PLSQL Developer, Toad, ... You can display the error.